# Angular 2 Reactive Form nested group passed null on reset throw error

Tags: forms, angular, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms, formgroups

I have this form group:

```
Id: [null],
Nominativo: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(100)]],
Area: fb.group({
    Id: [null]
})
```

When i try to reset the form with this model:

```
Id: 1,
Nominativo: 'Test'
Area: null
```

the area null value throw exception "TypeError: Cannot read property 'Id' of null". My expected result is all Area value become null. I can avoid this problem? My server response with all nested model null when they are all null

Comment: How you reset your form with model ?

Comment: i use form.reset(model). I tried form.patch(model) or form.setValue(model) but they return errors too

Comment: There is a open issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20509

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to do something like this:

area.model.ts

```
export class Area {
 id: string;
}
```

data.model.ts

```
export class DataModel {
 id: string;
 nominativo: string;
 area: Area;
}
```

form.model.ts

```
export class FormModel {
 id: string;
 nominativo: string;
 area?: Area;
}
```

data-model.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class DataModelService {
  toFormModel(dataModel: DataModel): FormModel {
    const form: FormModel = new FormModel();
    form.id = dataModel.id;
    form.nominativo = dataModel.nominativo;
    if (dataModel.area) {
      form.area = dataModel.area;
    }
    return form;
 }
}
```

form.component.ts

```
constructor(dataModelService: DataModelService,
            dataApi: dataApiService,
            fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.form = this.fb.group({
    id: '',
    nominativo: '',
    area: this.fb.group({
      id: ''
    })
  });

  this.dataApi.getData()
    .map((data: DataModel) => this.dataModelService.toFormModel(data))
    .subscribe((formData) => {
       this.form.patchValue(formData);
    });
}
```

Comment: if i replace the nested models with instantiated models all work fine (because he can access to Area.Id) but the problem is that the webapi return null values for the nested models empty so i need a solution without change them

Comment: I think the best solution will be write converter which tranform you data model (returned from api) to form model. Take a look:  https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#the-data-model-and-the-form-model, https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#save

Comment: First your should create form definition (ngOnInit) then after you receive data model from api transform it to form model definition and call form.setValue (also in ngOnInit after form definition)

Comment: The problem is that is a valid model (Area can be null). I would need something that tell to reset function to not call reset/setValue on nested formGroup when the object is null.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a simple clean solution for this. You need to iterate the object properties and set the values manually. So something like this:

```ts
resetVal = {Id:1, Nominativo: 'Test', Area: null }
```

and when you receive the data, you first check if `Area` is null, if so, set the formcontrols to `null` in that formgroup. If not, then set the values you get from backend to your formgroup:

```ts
this.areaCtrl = this.myForm.controls.Area as FormGroup;

this.myForm.patchValue({
  Id: this.resetVal.Id,
  Nominativo: this.resetVal.Nominativo,
}) 
if(this.resetVal.Area === null) {
  this.areaCtrl.patchValue({
    Id: null
  })
}
else {
  for(let a in this.resetVal.Area) {
    this.areaCtrl.patchValue({         
      [a]:this.resetVal.Area[a]
    })
  }
}
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jugvr7?file=app/app.component.ts)**